# For Loops and Logging Counters in Observable Notebooks

Tags: javascript, observablehq

I am trying to loop through an array, and print a counter number for every object in that array. I am starting with the following logic:

```
{for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   print(i)}
}
```

In Observable Notebooks (observablehq), this returns "undefined". So, I don't get any print statements. I am hoping to transfer this logic to loop through objects in an array, and count each object. But, I'm stuck with simply trying to use a counter!

I've also tried this:

```
import {log} from '@sorig/console-log-without-leaving-your-notebook'

{for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   console.log(i)}
}
```

This also returns 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` works fine inside Observable. I'm not sure if was a typo, but `print(i)` is not a javascript method, did you mean `console.log`? if you try the below snippet and open developer tools you will see lines printed.

```js
unamedcell = {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

However, remember that inside Observable you have a different flavor of javascript.

[Observable’s not JavaScript](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript)

It returns undefined because you're not naming the cells.

If I understand your needs, looping through an array of objects there. First name a cell with you data, you could also fetch from somewhere else. Then another cell using that data
Here is a fictitious case :

```js
data = {
  // your data
  const myObjects = [
    { a: 10, b: 20 },
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 1, b: 5 },
    { a: 2, b: 10 }
  ];
  return myObjects;
}
// data = Array(4) [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

then another cell

```js
dataExample = {
  let asum = 0;
  let bsum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    asum += data[i].a;
    bsum += data[i].b;
  }
  return { asum, bsum };
}
// dataExample = Object {asum: 14, bsum: 37}
```

More info on their [user manual](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/user-manual)

Comment: So I am trying now to do `data = {for (let i = 0; i < bees_in_canada_p2.total_results; i++){
   return(i)}
}` but this just returns data = 0. Could you please explain why I wouldn't get all instances of i that are less than the number I picked (total_results is an integer)

Comment: when you use the `return` statement you break the for loop cycle, so it starts with `i=0` then `return 0`. Could you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah right, well I guess I'm thinking in another language and not javascript -- I would like to do the equivalent of printing every instance of i until i reaches the number specified by the variable total_results. console.log does this in the browser console, but I'd like a way to return these results within the Observable console. I have a feeling I have to create an empty list and send the results there... would this be correct? If so, how would this look? Or if not, what am I not understanding?

Comment: I have now tried `newarray = [] ` then `data = {for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
   newarray.push[i]}
}` but this also returns an empty array

Comment: @BrendaThompson I see, you want to print as a return, remember on Observable each cell works like a function, so you can do this `data = {
  const newarray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    newarray.push(i);
  }
  return newarray;
}` Remember you have to return something so the namedCell will contain a value